# Downloading an asset from private repo on GitHub (PowerShell or .net)

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, github

I am trying to download an asset from a private repo. following [this documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#get-a-release-asset) it says in order to download the binary content you need to add to the header `Accept : application/octet-stream` but I get the following errors

> Invoke-WebRequest : {"message":"Unsupported 'Accept' header: 'application/octet-stream'. Must accept
> 'application/json'.","documentation_url":"https://docs.github.com/v3/media"}

I get the same error when I am trying it from .net 5.0 app using c#

> Response status code does not indicate success: 415 (Unsupported Media Type).

Here's my power shell code:

```
$headers.Add("Accept", "application/octet-stream")
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $downloadUri -Headers $headers -Out $extractPath
```

here's my c# code:

```
 dowlnloadRequest.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Accept", "application/octet-stream");
 var downloadResponse = await client.SendAsync(dowlnloadRequest);
 downloadResponse.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
```

P.S. I left out the setup code where I add the token and retrieving the asseturl

Comment: Sounds like the wrong URL but impossible to check, because you didn't provide it (you could x the owner and repo name and post the rest).

Comment: Hoop you are right I took the wrong URL. Thanks a million